# wifi connections not showing in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in Toshiba Satellite Laptop C850

Tags: command-line, internet, connection, toshiba-satellite

[image: Here is the pic for reference]Recently I updated my Ubuntu, my wifi connections were not showing up. Then I used a command `sudo apt-get autoremove` to set it right. This worked for me until today. I am getting no connections.

Even now, whenever I update any packages, my wifi connection gets disturbed.

Then all I do is turn off my laptop for a day or two, then it works fine suddenly. Isn't there any permanent solution to this?

I even tried this command: wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/curl_7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8_amd64.deb , but nothing seemed to work, ofcourse it was not fetching the source due to no connection

Comment: Please start here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180

Comment: I didn't understand. All I have to do is write that code and restart my pc?

Comment: You run the wireless info script on your computer. It creates a full diagnostic report that we can then examine to see where the trouble may be and therefore propose a solution. Since the report is quite long, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: How do i do that? Sorry I am new to ubuntu

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. You can copy text from a terminal. According to the output all is working. We need more details. That's why you were asked to run the script.

Comment: Which script are you talking about sir?

Comment: We are talking about  the wireless script I recommended in my comment above.

Comment: I dont understand. Where am I suppose to write that script?

Comment: The instructions are very clear at the link. You download the script; you then run (execute) the script: `./wireless_info` It produces a diagnostic report with most and probably all of the data we need to propose an answer. You then paste the report here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com We then click the link and read the report. We see what's gone wrong and write an answer.